# How to cancel AWS instance and stop Amazon AWS from billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds, billing

I opened a so-called "free tier" account on AWS to learn about cloud services.
Now my credit card is charged every month and is costing me a lot of money.

I looked at the billing and I saw a Amazon RDS service in a Zone in USA.
I thought to delete the RDS instance but it was not possible even after trying several times and as hard as I could (All possible options and several times)
RDS instance could not be deleted by any means.

I thought to "stop" the instance at least it would cost less money. I saw the instance was stopped but for unclear reasons it started after 7 days again.

After a lot of frustration I decided to delete my AWS account in an attempt to stop the billing and prevent a bankruptcy. Amazon AWS still is billing the running the instance even after deleting my AWS account.

Now I cannot even login to AWS and cannot do anything.
I know I could block my credit card and get a new one, but I costs time and I would rather keep my existing credit card.

I want to open a lawsuit against AWS Amazon since it clearly violates European laws.

Please help me to answer the following questions

1. how can I stop this billing and prevent Amazon AWS to charge my credit card?
2. Where Do I get contact with AWS support, for this level I only find community help but no direct contact with AWS Support.
3. Where can I find information about precedent cases to prepare a lawsuit?

Many thanks for your help, this is very important since it has a big financial impact for me.

Comment: Terminating account takes 90 days. From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/close-aws-account/): `After 90 days, any content remaining in your account will be permanently deleted, and AWS services that aren't already terminated will be terminated. ` Within this time, you can still [reopen](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reopen-aws-account/) the account to actually get to the bottom of why you can't delete an instance. Your post is not clear why you cant. Any errors? Are you the only user? Do you have any code running to would restart your db.

Comment: FYI, from [Stopping an Amazon RDS DB instance temporarily - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html): "You can stop a DB instance for up to seven days. If you don't manually start your DB instance after seven days, your DB instance is automatically started so that it doesn't fall behind any required maintenance updates."

Answer (score 2):

1. It is very easy to contact AWS support. There is a direct link in the navbar at the top right. AWS is actually pretty helpful when it comes to new users being accidentally overcharged. They will simply cancel your charges if you raised a ticket on time. https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?#/
2. What did you do to delete your account? I doubt your root account is deleted. Try logging in with root credentials (email and password) then raise a support ticket.
3. I can't give you legal advise but do you really intend to sue a company who you did not contact even though their support links are on every page of the their product?

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides a billing discount for certain AWS services. It is *not* a 'Free Account'.

You could contact AWS Customer Service (which is different to AWS Customer Support). They handle all billing-related queries.

Go to https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ and select **Billing or Account support**.

If you are unable to signing, go to: https://support.aws.amazon.com/#/contacts/aws-account-support/

Comment: Azure and Google Cloud Platform do offer a free account and they do not charge your credit card. Especially when you open such an account it is because you are not an expert using the platform.  It is possible to tell amazon that you are using the account for learning purpose?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All accounts are "Production" accounts. You can always give them suggestions via the "Feedback" button in the management console.